# ASP.net partial view relative action links

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to have action links which are relative to the current view.

For example, lets say I have a partial view which is a contains a paged list of news articles called `_ArticlesList`. I want to include this in the `Admin` and `Index` views, which are controlled by their relative controllers. `_ArticlesList` produces URLs which have the `routeValues` `pageNumber` and `pageSize`, but you have to hard code the controller, don't you?

I think what I want to do is just override properties in the `routeValue` object?

Edit:
I guess I could use `HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()`
but that looks pretty bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this to achieve what I wanted

```
public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string RelativeAction(this UrlHelper url, object routeValues)
    {
        var routeDataValues = url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values;
        var queryString = url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;

        foreach (string key in queryString.Keys)
        {
            routeDataValues[key] = queryString[key];
        }

        // Allow routeValue object to take precedence over queryString
        foreach (var prop in new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues))
        {
            routeDataValues[prop.Key] = prop.Value;
        }
        return url.RouteUrl(routeDataValues);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upload in For EX. Index file then write following to implement in your cshtml.

```
<div>
    @Html.Partial("_ArticleList", Model)
</div>
```

You can put this in any div tag.

Comment: That's not what I was asking. I think you should use `Html.RenderPartial` unless there is a specific reason as to why you need string returned.